# Why is $k$ left out of the equation $C_\text{all} = (k\epsilon_0A_1/d) + (\epsilon_0A_2/d)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

The capacitance of two capacitors in parallel is found using this formula:

$$C_{all}=C_1+C_2 \, .$$

Capacitance is

$$C=\frac{Q}{V} \, ,$$

and also

$$C=\frac{kε_0A}{d} \, ,$$

so can I say

$C_\text{all}=\frac{k\epsilon_0A_1}{d} + \frac{k\epsilon_0A_2}{d} \, .$

I see this in a problem I'm trying to figure out:

> $$C_\text{all}=\frac{k\epsilon_0A_1}{d} + \frac{\epsilon_0A_2}{d}$$

Why does $k$ not appear in the second part? The gap $d$ is the same for both capacitors.

I'm looking at #61 in this pdf: http://www.uccs.edu/~rtirado/Ch29%20ISM.pdf

Comment: Read question 61 more carefully and you'll see that, while capacitor $C_1$ has $k=4.8$, capacitor $C_2$ is, by constrast, air-filled.

Comment: Ahh thank you, there's no k when determining the capacitance w/o dielectric.

Comment: @slim The "k" value in that case is equal to one, since it is defined compared to a vacuum (air is approximately equal to that of a vacuum).

Comment: I thought k meant coulomb's constant. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that @John1024 has already answered the question, so In answering this just to close the question. As he said, the half-filled capacitor is modeled as 2 capacitors, one of which is air-filled ($k=1$) and one of which is filled with a dielectric ($k=4.8$).